# Java delete element from hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have HashMap from which I am trying to remove an element according to the following algorithm:

1. When a cell i is emptied, it is necessary to search forward through the following cells of the table until finding either another empty cell or a key that can be moved to cell i (that is, a key whose hash value is equal to or earlier than i).
2. When an empty cell is found, then emptying cell i is safe and the deletion process terminates.
3. But, when the search finds a key that can be moved to cell i, it performs this move. The search for a movable key continues for the new emptied cell, in the same way, until it terminates by reaching a cell that was already empty.

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing#Deletion

This is what I have for now, but looking at my tests, the instance is actually not deleted. Could you help me to figure out why? Thanks in advance

The outcome of hashFunction() is calculated hash value.

```
public class MyHashMap {

    Person[] array;

    public void remove(Person p) {
        int i = hashFunction(p);
        while (!p.equals(array[i])) {
            i = hashFunction(array[++i]);
        }
        int b;
        while (array[i] != null) {
            b = hashFunction(array[++i]);
            if (b <= hashFunction(array[i])) {
                Person newHash = array[i];
                array[i] = null;
                array[i++] = newHash;
                remove(array[i++]);
            }
            else if (array[++i] == null) {
                array[i] = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may want to revisit the use of ++i and i++. b = hashFunction(array[++i]); if (b <= hashFunction(array[i])). Wouldn't "b" always be hash of array[i]?

Comment: array[i] = null;array[i++] = newHash;  These both assign to same element.

Answer (score 0):

Your post-increment and pre-increment operators look to be contributing to your issue. For example,

```
array[i] = null;
array[i++] = newHash;
```

Here, you are assigning `null` to `array[i]` and then assigning `newHash` again to `array[i]` prior to `i` being incremented. You would actually want to use `++i` rather than `i++`.